# Button Click inside anchor tag not working in React Js Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dom-events

**Button** `onClick` not executing the `triggerThis`  function because it is wrapped with **react-router-dom** **Link** component

Expected behaviour: Card click should navigate to */app/url* and on button click the url navigation should be prevented and should run `triggerThis` function.

I want onClick button prevent navigation. but when i click outside button the navigation should work .. triggerThis is a function that just console.log("hello")

```
<Card>
    <Link to={`/app/url`}>
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>Paragraph</p>
       <button onClick={triggerThis}></button>
    </Link>
   
 </Card>
```

Comment: You *really* shouldn't place interactive elements within other interactive elements. What is the issue, specifically? Is the `button` element's `onClick` handler not calling `triggerThis` as expected? Can you update your question and include all relevant code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is `triggerThis`, what does it do? Do you want the button `onClick` handler to prevent the navigation from the link? Or you want these to be two separate "actions"? Please add a complete code example.

Comment: yes i want onClick button prevent navigation. but when i click outside button the navigation should work .. triggerThis is a function that just console.log("hello")

Answer (score 0):

You *really* shouldn't place interactive elements within other interactive elements, but if you want to allow the `button` to be independently clickable and not trigger the navigation of the wrapping `Link` component then you should stop the click event propagation. This prevents the click event from propagating further up the DOMtree to the `Link` element, thus preventing the navigation action from occurring.

Example:

```
const clickHandler = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  ...
};
```

...

```
<Card>
  <Link to="/app/url">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>
      ...
    </button>
  </Link>
</Card>
```